# MySQL GROUP BY year weirdness

Tags: mysql

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`ext_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`txt` text,
`url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`longitude` float(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`latitude` float(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`meta` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41695 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With data ranging from 2005 - 2013, all with data in the (int) timestamp column, this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y') as 'year',
COUNT(id) as 'total'
FROM items
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y')
```

Returns this:

```
'year' => null
'COUNT(*)' => string '38710' (length=5)

'year' => string '2011' (length=4)
'COUNT(*)' => string '45' (length=2)

'year' => string '2012' (length=4)
'COUNT(*)' => string '67' (length=2)

'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
'COUNT(*)' => string '90' (length=2)
```

Why don't I get a correct result?
When I iterate over a `SELECT * FROM items`, I get a correct date when printing `<?php print date('Y-m-d H:i', $item->timestamp); ?>`, so the date is in there.

Comment: have a look at the output of select * from items where DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y') is null

Comment: @palindrom - well, yeah, alot of nulls... but why is that? As I say, PHP can fetch the full date from any of the results.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - well, not all at once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT` wants a MySQL date type as its argument, not an integer that represents an UNIX timestamp. If you're storing your dates as UNIX timestamps (which you usually should not, by the way), then you need to convert it with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. Also there's a `YEAR()` function that returns a year, a bit more concise than using DATE_FORMAT.

So in a nutshell you want `YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))`

Comment: Awesome! I know I should use some sort of mysql date type, but this is the data I have.

Answer (score 1):

[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) accepts `date` as its first argument. You're giving an int.